# Java Midi: How do I change the pan of an individual note in a Sequence?

Tags: java, midi

This is what I have:

```
// Note on message
ShortMessage noteOnMessage = new ShortMessage();
noteOnMessage.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, chanNum, key, velocity);

// Pan change
ShortMessage panChangeMessage = new ShortMessage();
panChangeMessage.setMessage(ShortMessage.CONTROL_CHANGE, chanNum, SoundManager.PAN_CONTROLLER, pan);

// Note off message
ShortMessage noteOffMessage = new ShortMessage();
noteOffMessage.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, chanNum, key, 0);
```

The problem is that the panChangeMessage when added to the track changes the pan of ALL notes in that MidiEvent tick, not just the current individual note. Is there a way to change the pan of only 1 note?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Pan the channel over, and then pan it back after the note-off has been triggered. Keep in mind that any decay will be panned back.

Alternately, use multiple midi channels, one for each note of polyphony you need.